# Android development: Google Analytics Tracker doesn't work

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I also checked other answers here on SO, but I can't get my Google Analytics Tracker to work.

I followed this Google Documentation to set it all up: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced

I've created a Class called `gA.java` and have a main class called `MainActivity.java`. This is my `gA` class:

```
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

import java.util.HashMap;


public class gA extends MainActivity {
    private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-xxx-5";
    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
        GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
        ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company.
    }

    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

    public gA() {
        super();
    }
    synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
                    : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
                    : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
            mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }
}
```

And this is the part of my onCreate Method in my main class `MainActivity`, where you also can see the error:

[Click here](http://postimg.org/image/5mep1punb/)

In other answers at SO, they suggest to remove `getApplication`, but it still won't work.

Also there are suggestions like adding android:name to my manifest in `<application` but this shows me an error as well:

http://postimg.org/image/5da53ocyz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem comes from the fact that your gA class extends `MainActivity` when it should be extending the `Application` class. Using your own application class will help you a single instance of your tracker and will solve your type mismatch issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but which class could/should be `Application`?

Comment: Is it possible that `Application` is a predefined class and this tutorial didn't mean that `Application` should be my main application class (`MainActivitity`)?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think it works now. It started up without errors now. Can I test this locally if Google Analytics gets some data already or has this app to be published first? (It's my first app I want to publish)

Comment: Also, do you know if I have to put this code in every activity to track those activities or will this track my whole app?

Comment: Hi! Yeah Application is a class defined by the framework, you just have to extend it. If you want to check whether it works before publishing you can set the dry run mode to true on your tracker, this way nothing is sent to GA but it's logged in the logcat instead, it makes it easier to debug. I believe there is an autotracking option somewhere but I always go for manual tracking. You could place the logic in a "BaseActivity" and make all your activities extend this one.